# Configure assset publisher Liferay

Tags: liferay-6, assets

I want to configure the asset publisher to accept only one type of structures.
P.S: I have many asset publisher portlets and i need to every ona to have it's own structure ...

thank you

Liferay 6.2 ce ga2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Hit configuration icon > in source fieldset > Scope > Asset Type > select Web content Article > then in web content article subtype choose what u want

Hope it helps...